# VS2017 - 15.8.0 - Unable to deploy project to server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017

I just updated to the newest version of SSDT on VS2017 (from 15.7.5 to 15.8.0) and I am now receiving the following error when I try to connect to the server in the deployment wizard. Is anyone else receiving this error?

[image]

I get this error when trying to deploy multiple packages. However, when I login to a remote server with an older version of SSDT installed, I am able to both connect without error and deploy the package to the server. I think there may be a bug in the new SSDT update.

**Update - Additional problems:**

1. I can successfully build a script task, but when I close VSTA and click OK to save the changes I get an error saying that there is an error in the script.

[image]

2. When I close and re-open the package to execute the script task, I get an error: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." The script implements the WinSCPNet assembly to download from an SFTP.

Apparently, this is not the only problem: [VS2017 15.8.0 - no longer able to downgrade SQL version on SSIS package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51864919/4630376)

And, I have a deployment to production tomorrow. Smooth Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has acknowledged that this is a bug in Visual Studio. No ETA for a fix as of yet.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c063b57-8571-41e7-8a95-3ce4a105a5e3/unable-to-deploy-ssis-after-vs-2017-update-1580?forum=sqlintegrationservices