# VS2017 15.8.0 - no longer able to downgrade SQL version on SSIS package

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017

I updated to 15.8.0 yesterday. Today, when trying to change my SQL version to anything other than SQL 2017 the process crashes. I first tried rebuilding and that failed. I am currently removing 15.8.0 and reinstalling 15.7.6

I was unable to find anyone mentioning the issue and wanted to ask if anyone knew of a better way to fix it other than install an older Visual Studio version

Comment: Upvoted. Thank you for raising this and confirming. Saved me from performing a lengthy uninstall and re-install of VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c063b57-8571-41e7-8a95-3ce4a105a5e3/unable-to-deploy-ssis-after-vs-2017-update-1580?forum=sqlintegrationservices

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/311891/error-deploying-ssis-package.html

looks like there was an issue with 15.8.0

Answer (score 2):

I had problem populating data from database using LINQ in the visual studio 15.8.0 environment.
15.7.3 works well.

Comment: I was only able to find 15.7.6 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017) which did help but I have not found a way to get 15.8.0 to work yet